# Which is the sub-type function in this Scala example?

Tags: scala

I am reading through Scala-by-example (2014) by Martin Odersky.
On page 61 it is said that a function from type String to type Int is represented
as an instance of the trait Function1[String, Int]. Where Function1 is defined as:

`trait Function1[-A,+B] {def apply(x: A): B}`

It is also said further down that

> S=>T is a subtype of S'=>T', provided S' is a subtype of S, and T is a subtype of T'.

He uses the following code example:

`val f: (AnyRef => Int) = x => x.hashCode()
val g: (String => Int) = f 
g("abc")`

So here is my question please.
Since String is a subtype of AnyRef, I am assuming that in this example f represents a subtype of g. Is that correct?
If so please explain the logic in that determination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `V` is a subtype of `U`, then `V` can stand in anywhere that `U` can.

If you have an `AnyRef => Int`, can you use it any time you could use a `String => Int`?  Yes!  A `String` is an `AnyRef` so you can pass it in.

So, `AnyRef => Int` is a subtype of `String => Int`.  This relationship (which is kind of "backwards" from normal) is described by saying that functions are *contravariant* in their arguments.

That said the *instances* `f` and `g` don't necessarily have any relationship.  But their types do.

Answer (score 0):

f and g functions, and functions have a type variance, which allows for subtypes and supertypes of type parameters: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/variances.html

Running the following code in the scala terminal will give you the same result as running the example.

g is declared as a fuction of type (AnyRef => Int), which would implement Function as:

```
val f = new Function[AnyRef /*or any supertype*/,Int /*or any subType type*/] {
   def apply(x: AnyRef): Int = x.hashCode()
}
```

It is defined as a function that takes in a parameter of type `AnyRef`, returns an `Int`.

g is then defined as a function that takes in a `String` and returns an `Int`.  It is set equal to f, so it becomes this:

```
val g = new Function[String /*Supertype of AnyRef*/, Int] {
    def apply(x: String): Int = x.hashCode()
}
```

Although, g is not a new function in this case.  g is just another reference to f. Essentially, g is f typecasted to `Function[String, Int]`.

Edit: Since AnyVal is a subtype of Int, you can do this too:

```
val gg: (String => AnyVal) = f
```